# Can't make vimeo api call when logged in, work when logged out

Tags: angularjs, vimeo-api, satellizer

I've implemented Satellizer (https://github.com/sahat/satellizer).

Now when I log in, any vimeo api calls made returns

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Authorization Required)
error:"You must provide a valid authenticated access token."
```

What I don't understand is why this happens even though the vimeo api call is correct and has the access_token in the url next to the above mentioned error message.

```
https://api.vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/videos?access_token=c57cd8d4fxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vimeo is not looking for the access token as a query paramenter. When you add it to the url like you have done, it is a query parameter. You need to include the access token in the Authorization header instead.

On GitHub you can find a PHP client library. In my experience, that has been quite straight forward to use. It works great out of the box if you do not want to setup your requests. Here is the library: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php

Comment: This is correct (I work at Vimeo) >>> auth header instead of query param.